# Can't load wireguard module

Tags: 18.04, server, kernel, modprobe, wireguard

I have a VPS server running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS where I wanted to install a WireGuard VPN service. I have started with adding the repository and then installing the module which is running fine and without any error messages.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:wireguard/wireguard
apt-get update
apt-get install wireguard-dkms wireguard-tools
```

Then, I wanted to load the kernel module using

```
sudo modprobe wireguard
```

but, `modprobe` tells me, that it is unable to locate the kernel module.

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:514 lookup_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/4.15.0/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module wireguard not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0
```

Rereading the console output, the installer told me that it had installed the module to `/lib/modules/4.15.0-62-generic/updates/dkms`, but `modprobe` seems to look only into `/lib/modules/4.15.0/`. I have already tried to create a symlink into the 4.15.0-directory, but `modprobe` still is not able to locate the module file.

The Ubuntu Server was 'out of box', since I was renewing it. Is anyone who can help?

Answer (score 11):

Closely reading the output of `sudo apt-get install wireguard` showed the following lines for me:

```
Building for 4.15.0-70-generic 4.15.0-72-generic
Module build for kernel 4.15.0-70-generic was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

Installed missing kernel headers via `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

Then retry package installation via `sudo apt-get remove wireguard` followed by `apt-get install wireguard`.

Now `sudo modprobe wireguard` doesn't complain, and `lsmod | grep wireguard` shows:

```
wireguard             212992  0
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 wireguard
udp_tunnel             16384  1 wireguard
```

Comment: Installing missing kernel headers is the key thx! sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname --kernel-release) && sudo modprobe wireguard

Comment: This doesn't work under WSL :(